# Where do functions for which $\partial_x\partial_y \neq \partial_y \partial_x$ fit in the theory of distributions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory

Consider $f$ defined  on $\mathbb R^2$ by
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq 0 \\ 0 & (x,y)= 0\end{cases}$$ It is known that  [$\partial_x \partial_y f \neq \partial_y \partial_x f $](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Failure_of_Clairaut's_theorem_where_both_mixed_partials_are_defined_but_not_equal).  However, the following is also true: note that  $f\in L^1_{\text {loc}}$, and so defines a distribution $T_f$, and since any test function $\phi$ is smooth,
$$ \langle \partial_x \partial_y T_f,\phi\rangle = \langle  T_f,\partial_y \partial_x\phi\rangle = \langle  T_f,\partial_x \partial_y\phi\rangle = \langle \partial_y \partial_x T_f,\phi\rangle $$ 
So the distributional derivatives commute (and distributional derivatives always do). What's going on? I would guess that $T_{\partial_x \partial_y f}$, $T_{\partial_y \partial_x f}$, and $\partial_y\partial_x T_f$ are three distinct distributions.  Is $\partial_y\partial_x T_f$ not given by a function?

Comment: I think that the derivative in the distributional sense agrees with the usual derivative *if* the function is differentiable. However, even though your second partial derivatives exist, the function is not twice differentiable, so I would not expect the distributional derivative(s) to match the usual one(s).

Comment: The mixed partials of $f$ only differ at one point: that is not going to affect the distribution they define.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  thats an excellent point...so all three distributions are equal...? I see no issues in passing to $\epsilon\to 0$ for the computations 
$$ (\partial_x \partial_y T, \phi) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} f  \phi_{xy}  = \int f_{xy} \phi = \int f_{yx} \phi$$
since all boundary terms vanish in the limit, using $\|f\|_{L^\infty}<\infty$, etc. and DCT...